# No DefaultInterface in TCppWebBrowser

Tags: c++builder, rad-studio, c++builder-2010

I have a problem with the web browser memory leak - which I've found here:
[How can I hide WebBrowser till the website complete the loading / download process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22611846/how-can-i-hide-webbrowser-till-the-website-complete-the-loading-download-proce)

The solution is to use `browser.DefaultInterface.Document` instead of `browser.Document`.

I was using this:

```
DelphiInterface<IHTMLDocument2> diDoc = browser->Document;
```

But I am using `TCppWebBrowser` and it only has `browser->DefaultDispatch` doesn't have `DefaultInterface` like `TWebBrowser` which I *assume* is the same thing but I don't know how to query TCppWebBrowser for `IHTMLDocument2` to avoid the memory leak, until I fully switch to newer version of RAD Studio where the memory leak has been fixed (Sydney, currently on 2010).

I tried this:

```
DelphiInterface<IHTMLDocument2> diDoc;
browser->DefaultDispatch->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDocument2, &diDoc);
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

This works... but...

```
DelphiInterface<IHTMLDocument2> diDoc = browser->DefaultDispatch;
```

But the resulting diDoc is NULL. (it is not NULL for `browser->Document` which is also `_di_IDispatch`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved this myself. Instead of:

```
DelphiInterface<IHTMLDocument2> diDoc =
browser->Document;
```

I simply used:

```
#include <SHDocVw.hpp> // required for Shdocvw::IWebBrowser2
#include "SHDocVw_OCX.h"    // TCppWebBrowser

DelphiInterface<IHTMLDocument2> diDoc =
DelphiInterface<Shdocvw::IWebBrowser2>(browser->DefaultDispatch)->Document;
```

This also seems to work:

```
DelphiInterface<IHTMLDocument2> diDoc =
DelphiInterface<Shdocvw::IWebBrowser2>(browser->Application)->Document;
```

Alternatively:

```
DelphiInterface<IHTMLDocument2> diDoc = ((_di_IDispatch)browser->DefaultDispatch)->Document;
DelphiInterface<IHTMLDocument2> diDoc = ((_di_IDispatch)browser->Application)->Document;
```

The memory leak seems to be addressed with this just like in case of the Delphi equivalent linked in the answer above.